# migration java 7 to java 8 - forEach and addAll in a Set?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

My java7 code:

```
String[] packagesName = ...
final Set<Class<?>> result = new HashSet<>();
for (final String packageName : packagesName) {
    result.addAll(new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false)).getSubTypesOf(Step.class));
}
return result;
```

I try with `stream` + `flatMap` + `map` + `collect`

```
packagesName.stream().flatMap(packageName -> new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false)).getSubTypesOf(Step.class)).collect(...??
```

Comment: Why did you change working code?

Comment: does `new Reflections(p...)` return a `Collection`?

Comment: Is it possible to apply stream directly with array? I suppose you need to convert them first. And i suppose your second syntext is right just need to add Collection.toSet() inside collect().

Comment: @Kayaman, you have to live with your time and use the new features of the java language.

Comment: @sgrillon for new code, yes. There's no need to convert loops into streams just because they were introduced. It's not a replacement, it's an addition. If you had a legacy codebase that used `Vector`, I doubt you'd start converting them to `ArrayList` everywhere (or would you?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays::stream` to convert `String` array to `Stream` of Strings and then use `Stream::flatMap` and collect to `Set` using [`Collectors.toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) :

```
Set<Class<?>> result = Arrays.stream(packagesName)
                .flatMap(packageName -> new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false)).getSubTypesOf(XPath.Step.class).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Of course in this case you could also use `Stream.of` instead of `Arrays.stream`.

Comment: You prefert `Stream.of(packagesName)` or `Arrays.stream(packagesName)`? or same result?

Comment: In this case it will be the same because `Stream.of` calls `Arrays.stream` underneath. For non-primitive arrays it is same, the difference would be visible if you wanted to pass for example `int[]` - primitive type array.

Answer (score 1):

The `flatMap` needs a function that returns a stream as parameter

```
return packagesName.stream()
    .flatMap(packageName -> new Reflections(packageName,
            new SubTypesScanner(false)).getSubTypesOf(Step.class).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Sorry, my `packagesName` is a array of String (I edit my question with this info)

Comment: You prefert `Stream.of(packagesName)` or `Arrays.stream(packagesName)`? or same result?

Answer (score -1):

Dont have access to Step.class , just as an illustration!

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SO58133558 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final Set<Class<?>> result = ImmutableList.of("java.sql","java.lang").stream().
            map(packageName -> {
              return new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false)).
                      getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
            }).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```